# String Format Exception PRIu64

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, format

I am working on cRTMPServer, however the documentation is sparse and the Google Groups page is also inactive. Contacting the project creators has not succeeded either.

I've dug down into the code, and it's simply a case of getting the log file to register. Following a breakpoint and F11-ing all the way down into the code, the bug is here.

```
string temp = format("%s.%"PRIu64".%"PRIu64, STR(_fileName), (uint64_t) getpid(), (uint64_t) ts);
```

This is the line that throws the exception.

```
    uint64_t x = (uint64_t) getpid();
    uint64_t y = (uint64_t) ts;
    string z = STR(_fileName);
```

Here, i have captured the values, to see what they are.

```
x = 4696
y = 1400765769698
z = 'main.log'
```

I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012.

Any obvious mistakes here? The code seems to work for other people, however i don't receive an build errors. Which makes me think that all included files are there.

PRIu64 is related in to inttypes.h, but as i have said, there is not build error for missing headers etc.

ERROR MESSAGE in memcpy.asm on the line...

```
rep     movsd           ;N - move all of our dwords
```

Unhandled exception at 0x6B30108E (msvcr110d.dll) in crtmpserver.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00001258.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in Visual Studio 2012.

IntTypes and StdInt conflict and this bug has been fixed in VS2013